# Magento2: css file modification does not apply

Tags: magento2, css, cms-pages, less-css

I am using Magento 2.2.4 and I need to design my website with the size of 70%. I am trying to override the css by a theme /custom_theme/web/css/style.css file as follows. But it didn't work. How to resolve this?

```
`.page-wrapper{width:70%}`
```

Comment: Why are you adding this to direct css? Did you add these css file to your head?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I am creating a custom theme and I have put this file into that directory's css directory. No I didn't add this in the header

Comment: Then call your CSS file from default.xml in your theme

Comment: @SukumarGorai It doesn't apply the style changes even after including in the header